# Team City - Connect and remove agents questions

Tags: teamcity-8.0

I had 3 Agents (A, B and C). For test purposes, I´ve installed a fourth one (D), but I didnt know that my license was up to 3 Agents only. So, the agent D was created with "Unauthorized with comment: Agent teamcityagentdev4 cannot be authorized because there is not enough licenses" status. Its understandable, but a weird thing happened to another Agent A, that was working well so far. The Agent A  status changed to "Disconnected (Agent has unregistered)". Now, I got 2 questions:

1) How can I delete the Agent D ? There is no button "Remove agent" in Agent Summary tab in TC Web UI. I tried to disable this Agent in order to get that button, but its still missing.

2) How can I reconnect the Agent A ? I tried to restart the Agent windows service, but nothing happened.

I also searching in Team City documentation, but I didnt found anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stop Agent service on Agent D to get it removed from Agents tab.

Also, you might want to check Agent A's logs to figure out what happened. You can try restarting Agent A's service after stopping Agent D's service

Answer (score 0):

Stop the agent service.
Now in the agents tab you can see that particular agent disconnected. Now a new option(button) appears 'Remove Agent'. Click that and your agent gets deleted/removed.